# Bootstrap - making the margins / space in the hero unit container smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The hero unit in Bootstrap seems to have a large margin area between the outer edge and the text & buttons.  Is there a Bootstrap-friendly way to make this margin area smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you should just be able to edit the hero unit in your own custom stylesheet (or in the bootstrap.css if you really want):

```
.hero-unit {
  padding: 30px; /* default is 60px; */
}
```

Haven't tested this, but if above code doesn't work, just add `!important`, which overrides all other style rules (including inline styles):

```
padding: 30px !important;
```

Comment: Thanks - the first answer worked, but it also told a design noob what the !important attribute markup is used for (I didn't previously know of its existence).